# Cannot install nuget package (Python, chocolatey, NodeJS)

Tags: python, node.js, powershell

Inside log file there is a discription of attempting to install NuGet Package, but it fails in running process (python 3.10.1 installation).
Can I solve this installation failure by editing command or adding some params like "--force"

**Here's the command I'm using in CMD:**

'''

```
chocolatey install python -y --force
```

'''

**Here's the message from the log file while installing nodejs and dependencies:**
'''

```
2021-12-22 16:20:22,434 3788 [INFO ] -  The install of python was successful.
2021-12-22 16:20:22,436 3788 [INFO ] -   Software install location not explicitly set, it could be in package or
  default install location of installer.
2021-12-22 16:20:22,437 3788 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\Users\support9\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\python.3.10.1.nupkg".
2021-12-22 16:20:22,443 3788 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 1/2 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2021-12-22 16:20:22,444 3788 [INFO ] - 
2021-12-22 16:20:22,445 3788 [ERROR] - Failures
2021-12-22 16:20:22,447 3788 [ERROR] -  - python3 (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2021-12-22 16:20:22,449 3788 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-12-22 16:20:22,467 3788 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 1603
```

'''

**Try to give some issues how I can modify the process of downloading and installing pkg.**

Comment: what is the error message in the log file ? We can see that it is telling that the ps1 failed to execute but first check the chocolatey.log file to see what is the issue and also debug your script first and see where it is failing. Isolate the things layer wise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you are you running CMD with elevated rights? (Administrator)

also please check if you set the execution policy for powershell, you can easily check this with running the

> Get-ExecutionPolicy

command in a powershell window.

for all my testing purposes i've set the execution policy to unrestricted.
Note that this is only adviced for testing.

Greetings,
Testeagle.

Comment: Didn't help running installation inside PShell and editing value of ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted

Comment: It seems like a rights issue too me, is there anymore extended logging you could provide?